# Why does CLGeocoder return the wrong region for the USA?

Tags: swift, core-location

I have a requirement to centre a MapKit map on a country, based on the country's region identifier.  When I use `CLGeocoder` to get the placemark for most identifiers it returns good results, but when I use "US" as the region identifier I get a placemark with the following region:

> CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+42.31077535,+0.00000000> radius 13876457.74', center:<+42.31077535,+0.00000000>, radius:13876457.74m)

As you can see the longitude is 0 - which is incorrect - and the radius is much too big.

Here's an abridged version of the code:

```swift
guard let regionId = Locale.current.region?.identifier
  preconditionFailure()
}
        
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

do {
    let results = try await  geocoder.geocodeAddressString(regionId)

    print(results)
}
```

How can I reliably get a valid region that shows a country based on its region identifier?

Comment: I think the region is just broken for the USA. It works fine for Great Britain and FWIW the location in the place mark is correct. It's right in the middle of the mainland USA